# WPF binding not raising Property changed event for Data Template Type expander

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate, inotifypropertychanged

The xaml property bind to the view model only gets the value once the UI is loaded, on any changes the Raise property changed event is not raised and is not updated with the latest value.

I have one more xaml where the same implementation works as expected, but the only difference is this xaml contains **Data Template** because of which all the properties in this view model doesn't fire Raise property changed event and update the UI on any changes.

This is my Property in the View Model

```
 public bool IsDataValid
    {
        get        
        {return isDattaValid;}
        set
        {        
            isDattaValid = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("IsDataValid");
        }
    }
```

This is the my xaml

```
 <Expander Grid.Row="6" x:Name="AdvanceSettingsExpander">
        <Expander.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="serviceTemplateKey">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                    
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,6,0" Foreground="Red" Text= "!"                                
                               Visibility="{Binding IsDataValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConv},  Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,6,0" Text="Advance Settings for "></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,6,0" Text=":"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock  Margin="0,0,6,0" 
                       Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="Auto"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Expander.Resources>
        <Expander.Header>
            <ContentControl  Content="{Binding Path=ConfiguredServices}" 
                         ContentTemplate="{StaticResource serviceTemplateKey}">                   
            </ContentControl>
        </Expander.Header> 
        <ContentControl
            Content="{Binding Path=RemDevAdvanceSettingHostingContent}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsAdvConfigAllowed}"            
            Margin="4,0,0,0" Height="Auto"/>
    </Expander>
```

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay`, `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True` and  `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless. You should remove that.

Comment: @Clemens : Yes. Its not required, just added if it could help in updating the property changed values. Since No harm in adding it

Comment: Besides that, you are sure that the `IsDataValid` property of the object held by the `ConfiguredServices` property is changing? Are there any data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug the application?

Comment: Yes IsDataValid object keeps on changing. In the debug session the control comes inside set method various time changing its value . But the binding doesnt get refreshed after set.
There are no binding errors in the output window

Binding is successful but changes are not getting reflected

Comment: Please can somebody help